# how to multiple number in 2 the multiple the result in 2 10 times in c++?

Tags: c++

How to multiple number in 2 the multiple the result in 2 (10 times)

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    for (int x=1 ;x<=10; x++){
        for (int i=1;i=x++;i*2) {
            cout<<i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it is give me error what is wrong ?

please help .

Comment: i tried many other code but this is the last one all of them is wrong

Comment: your inner `for` loop contains an expression `i=x++` what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Are you trying to show 2 4 8 16 32 64 ...?  It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? You need to study the `for` loop to understand the syntax, particularly the conditional.

Comment: @AbdalrhmanMostafa please mention the desired output and also the error logs. Also, it is not clear what are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Abrar what is the correct code to multiple number in 2 the multiple the result in 2 (10 times)

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

`i=x++` is not an appropriate stopping conditional in the second loop (it's never `false`), and so eventually a signed integral type will overflow.

Comment: i know it's a mistake i removed it but i forgot to remove it here 
i tried this code and also wrong 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int z;
 cin>>z;
for (int x=1 ;x<=10; x++)
{
 
cout<<z*2<<endl;
}
 }

 
 
 return 0;
}